# On update entity with version_id column (Optimistic Offline Lock)

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I am facing the following problem while I am trying to update some values on an entity with version_id column.

Here is the snippet of code which I am using:

```
BASE = declarative_base()
class Job(BASE):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'

    id = Column(String(36), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    worker_id = Column(String(36), nullable=True)
    status = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
    timeout = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    version_id = Column(String(36))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'version_id_col': version_id,
        'version_id_generator': lambda version: uuid.uuid4()
    }
```

Approach #1 for updating a job entity:

```
query = session.query(Job)
            .filter_by(id=job_id)
            .update({'worker_id': worker_id, 'timeout': new_timeout)
```

SQLAlchemy generated the following query (mysql.log):

```
UPDATE jobs 
SET worker_id='4a2350a1-f3ce-48f9-b29f-cc22e2e625fd', 
timeout='2014-03-22 09:47:04.337521' 
WHERE jobs.id ='84844301-446a-4912-85d7-92d9d462de5b'
```

Approach #2 for updating a job entity:

```
job = session.query(Job).filter_by(id=job_id).first(); 
job.worker_id = worker_id
job.timeout = new_timeout
session.add(job); 
session.flush()
```

SQLAlchemy generated the following query (mysql.log):

```
UPDATE jobs 
SET worker_id='1634939b-d3c6-462d-8254-d7f09640ba71', 
timeout='2014-03-22 11:10:51.879507', 
version_id='aa9d3f74-3e4a-4bae-af38-fe0530dbf9b7' 
WHERE jobs.id = '3e6ab855-179e-4f4f-bf3a-847cf19b30fa' 
AND jobs.version_id = '2c1288ba-ad27-444c-9f56-764df4898c52'
```

We can notice with Approach#1 the version_id column was never considered but in Approach#2 it was taken into consideration.

I thought even with Approach#1 sqlalchemy will be using the class_mapper.

Couldn't understand why is this difference of behavior.

Can someone please help me to understand why with Approach#1 the update call did not take into consideration the version_id column? OR am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I could find any answer, went ahead and posted my question in 'sqlalchemy-dev' group.

Thanks to Michael Bayer for sparing his time to answer my question.

Thought would share the link to the answer here for benefiting others.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy-devel/JUqlWKtRa4g